# view of the page broken when personal hotspot feature turned on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I turn on personal hot spot connection, my entire layout pushed down but only horizontal scrollview stays at original place due to this reason the view of the page looks broken. How can I set this feature so the view of the page looks appropriate.

Comment: Excuse me , did you turn on the personal hotspot by objective-C or turn on the personal hotspot by setting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the autoresize mask property of your views (and possible your subviews).

If the autoresize mask allows the view to stretch, and it is not pinned to both the top and bottom, the view will resize as expected under this circumstance.

Comment: The status bar is 40 pixels high instead of 20 when personal hotspot is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Set the autoresizingMask property of any element to None so that the elements look exactly the same relative to each others.

```
someView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```