# Personal hotspot breaks layout on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, layout, hotspot

My layout is broken when I turn of my personal hotspot, when my personal hotspot is on, it goes well, but the layout stays the same when my personal hotspot is turned of.

I have RootViewController which view I have added to my window

In that rootviewController I have a navigationcontroller which view I have added to my rootviewcontroller's view, and all my viewcontrollers are pushed on to the navigationcontroller.

anybody have a clue why this happens?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078697/view-of-the-page-broken-when-personal-hotspot-feature-turned-on

Comment: Also, check the Apple guidelines for sizing of your display and handling these situations (like when in a call, etc)

Comment: I looked at that question but it doesn't work for me, i don't know exactly which view i need to set my auroresize mask for

Comment: Excuse me , did you turn on the `personal hotspot` by `objective-C` or turn on the `personal hotspot` by setting ?

Comment: @Andy Jacobs, How did you solve this? I have the same issue, can you share me your solution?

Comment: I cannot remember exactly what i did to fix this as this is more than 3 years ago but using autoresizing mask & tap in on layoutsubviews could be a good start.